# Setting up GIT for development server

Tags: git, gitlab

Currently we have the following situation/problem:

Our developers work **local**

Developer **pushes his changes to the repository** on the git server ( all is fine up until now, because on GitLab I've set the ssh-key and the person can clone/pull/push )

On the **development server** I need this to be **pulled from git** and here's where the **issue** start.

We have **1 development server**, with **>20 websites**, so as I see it that's **20 users** that I need to put in git seeing we plan on using it for all and **create an ssh-key for each of those users seperatly**, to be able to have the acces to **pull the changes** that were made to the repository)

The above basically goes the same for our live server.

I am at an loss how to approach this, is there a centralised way that I can simply give acces on server level to pull the changes? I have been looking at it for about 1.5 months now, might be looking at it the wrong way.

To add: We have around 14 servers running, so there's that.

Comment: What about "Deploy-Keys"?

Comment: Why do you insist on an account for every website? Why not create a generic account "dev-server" that will be used for all Git activities on the server (I assume these are build/automation activities).

Comment: @EldadAK I don't insist on using an account for every website, it's just that when I use a different account, I feel like I get in trouble when we would need to edit on the development website, seeing you pull with a different owner, and the original owner cant write in it anymore. We also might not be able to get all website local. It's a reason why we've done it per user before, sadly I don't know any different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: [Gitlab SSH Readme](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html)

> Deploy keys
>
> Deploy keys allow read-only access to multiple projects with a single SSH  key.
>
> This is really useful for cloning repositories to your Continuous Integration (CI) server. By using deploy keys, you don't have to setup a dummy user account.
>
> If you are a project master or owner, you can add a deploy key in the project settings under the section 'Deploy Keys'. Press the 'New Deploy Key' button and upload a public SSH key. After this, the machine that uses the corresponding private key has read-only access to the project.
>
> You can't add the same deploy key twice with the 'New Deploy Key' option. If you want to add the same key to another project, please enable it in the list that says 'Deploy keys from projects available to you'. All the deploy keys of all the projects you have access to are available. This project access can happen through being a direct member of the project, or through a group. See def accessible_deploy_keys in app/models/user.rb for more information.
>
> Deploy keys can be shared between projects, you just need to add them to each project.

Comment: How have I never seen this?

I created key on my development as root user and it was placed /root/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub) assuming this is standard location, however, when I switch to for example user1 on that server to pull from the repository GitLab doesn't seem to see it, or it's not working ( asking for git password, as it does with accounts that try to pull that don't have acces ) 

I think I'm missing something.

Am I on this way, not still stuck with a lot of users on GitLab ( because of the users on the server ), if I pull as one different user, then another user can't edit right?

Comment: I would recommend that you have a single user on your deployment environments, let's call them `deploy` because creative naming is hard. That has the single responsibility of pulling down code using their ssh public key (added as a read only deploy key for all relevant projects). Then you can have that user git clone or git pull (or your preferred deployment method) the code to the server in whatever location is appropriate and have each app run under a user specific to that application.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It might be me being very unexperienced, and this might be a stupid question. How can user "deploy" acces the files of "user1" or any other users, as it's not a root? Also if I pull as the user "deploy" on that development server, in that website the files ( which are previously owned by user1 ) will now be of the user deploy, meaning the owner of the website (user1 ) can not edit that file anymore, this is scenario sometimes happens on us.

Comment: Other than creating new temporary files the user running the application shouldn't be making changes to the deployed files, but if for some reason it does need to, you can always use `chown` to change the ownership of the files to the appropriate user as part of your deploy script.

Comment: I've marked you as the answer, thank you very much.

In addition I have 1 last question.
The user "deploy" should have acces to all the user's files right? What is best practice to approach this? Using a FACL and setting up that the newcoming users will also be accesable from "deploy"

Comment: The best practice would be to have the deploy user drop the files in a shared location (probably under /opt/) and have init scripts for your system (systemd, upstart, or whatever else you are using) manage the running of the applications with the correct users and log file maintenance, etc.

Comment: Oke that got complicated for me quickly.. Would giving rights to access other folders for the deploy user be sufficient for the time? And is there any documentation / tutorial or information available regarding to what you've just mentioned for my situation? I'm pretty new in total with Linux etc

Comment: [The Redhat systemd docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_File_Create) should get you started on the subject of setting services up in systemd. While setting the permissions up should be enough to get things running, and then you can refine your processes as you learn new things.

Comment: I appreciate that you gave me a point to start looking at, and I'll go with giving rights to the deploy user first so it can acces other users and write/read first, and then refine as you said.

Thank you for your help.